# A proof involving functions

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

1. Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ be an $m$ -dimensional subspace. For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define $S_{\mathbf{v}}=\{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}: \mathbf{w} \in W\}$, and let $U=\left\{S_{\mathbf{v}}: \mathbf{v} \in V\right\}$. Define addition in $U$ so that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$
   $$
   S_{\mathbf{x}}+S_{\mathbf{y}}=S_{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}
   $$
   and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$
   k S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{k \mathbf{x}}
   $$
   It can be shown that $U$ is vector space (you do not need to prove this).

Let $T: V \rightarrow V^{\prime}$ be a linear transformation. Let $W=\operatorname{ker}(T)$, let $U$ be as defined above, and for each $\mathbf{v} \in V$ define
$$
\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{v}}\right)=T(\mathbf{v}) (*)
$$
Since it is possible for $S_{\mathbf{v}}=S_{\mathbf{w}}$ with $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{w}$, it is not immediately clear that $\phi$ is well defined. Prove that $(*)$ does indeed define a function $\phi: U \rightarrow V^{\prime}$, by showing that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$ satisfying $S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{\mathbf{y}}$ we have $\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{x}}\right)=\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{y}}\right)$.

To prove the above this is what I have done:

Let $T: V \rightarrow V^{\prime}$ be a linear transformation.

Let $W=\operatorname{ker}(T)$.

It is already defined that $S_{v}=\{v+w: w \in W\}$ and $U=\left\{S_{v}: v \in V\right\}$.

Now define a function $\phi: U \rightarrow V^{\prime}$ such that $\phi\left(S_{v}\right)=T(v)$.

To prove that $\phi$ is a well defined function.

That is, to prove,

$S_{x}=S_{y} \Rightarrow \phi\left(S_{x}\right)=\phi\left(S_{y}\right)$

Let $S_{x}, S_{y} \in U$

Assume that $S_{x}=S_{y}$.

$\begin{aligned} S_{x} &=S_{y} \\\{x+w: w \in W=k e r T\} &=\left\{y+w^{\prime}: w^{\prime} \in W=k e r T\right\} \\ T(x+w) &=T\left(y+w^{\prime}\right) \end{aligned}$

$T(x)+T(w)=T(y)+T\left(w^{\prime}\right)$ since $T$ is a linear transformation

$T(x)=T(y)$ since $w$ and $w^{\prime} \in k e r T$

$\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ by definition

Hence the proof.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Where is the definition of $U$?

Comment: @M.Nestor. Thank you for pointing that out, edited my post to include more information including the definition of U.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S_x = S_y$ and $x \in S_x$, $x \in S_y$. So $x = y + w_0$ for some $w_0 \in W$. Thus we have

$$\phi(S_x) = T(x) = T(y + w_0
) = T(y) = \phi(S_y)$$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.